# Why do many software packages in Ubuntu have the letter 'g' appended?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Hellu.

Why do many packages in Ubuntu/debian have the letter 'g' in front of their name? Examples of this are such as:

- **g**edit
- **g**parted
- **g**anyremote
- **g**vncviewer
- **g**whois

My first quick guess would be it's a shortname for "gnome" however I cannot find any particularly good information about it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Please excuse me but I'm extremly confused what tag(s) could fit this question; please update it if you have any recommendations.

Comment: the same for example `qbittorrent` where `q` stands for QT GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was very nicely pointed out to me, that these letters are in place to prevent the OSes from using the same names for different programs. Also to make it easier to see what OS the package belongs to.

The ones you listed are for the GNOME Desktop. They work in other environments, they were just developed in GNOME. If you type in `man gedit` it shows you the name, and this is what it shows.

`gedit - text editor for the GNOME Desktop`

The same rule applies to apps like `k3b` a burning application for K Desktop Environment.

`k3b - KDE CD burning program`

`k3b` can be installed into GNOME or other environments by typing in

`sudo apt-get install k3b`

When a application gets installed into another desktop environment, it grabs dependency files that work for the environment it was developed for.  It does not install the actual Desktop Environment though.

**NOTE:** this is not always true.  I suggest when in doubt, check the `man page` or developers site as they should show you why it is named what it is.

Comment: it does not answer the why: to prevent 2 OS'es (back then gnome and kde) using the same name for different programs and to make it easy to see for us humans to what OS a package belongs to ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind thank you for that info.  I have updated my answer to reflect your comment here!  :-)